# html, javascript, how to know when checkbox change state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

My goal is to show `divX2`when `x2` is checked either by clicking `x2` or clicking `xt`. This works fine when `x2` is clicked but doesn't work when `xt` is clicked. Note the line `console.log("change x2");` in the `change` event handler of `x2`. When I clic `xt`, `x2` looks checked but the `change` event is never fired.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#xt").click(function() {
    var check = $(this).prop("checked");
    $(".mark").prop("checked", check);
  });

  $("#x2").change(function() {
    console.log("change x2");
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      $("#divX2").show();
    } else {
      $("#divX2").hide();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><span><input name="xt" id="xt" type="checkbox" /> Check All</span></li>
  <li><span><input name="x1" id="x1" type="checkbox" class="mark" /> X1</span></li>
  <li><span><input name="x2" id="x2" type="checkbox" class="mark"/> X2</span></li>
  <li><span><input name="x3" id="x3" type="checkbox" class="mark"/> X3</span></li>
  <li><span><input name="x4" id="x4" type="checkbox" class="mark"/> X4</span></li>
</ul>
<div id="divX2" hidden="hidden">
  <h4>Mostrando X2</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to call .change() to fire it.

`$(".mark").prop("checked", check).change();`

Comment: The only valid answer here

Answer (score 0):

the .change not fires when you assigned to him property value by other function

> change event only fires when the user types into the input and then loses focus,

use this :

```
$(function (){
            $("#xt").click(function (){
                var check = $(this).prop("checked");
                $(".mark").prop("checked", check);
                if($(this).prop("checked")){
                    $("#divX2").show();
                }
                else if(!$("#x2").prop("checked")) {
                    $("#divX2").hide();
                }
            });

            $("#x2").change(function (){
                console.log("change x2");
                if($(this).prop("checked")){
                    $("#divX2").show();
                }
                else{
                    $("#divX2").hide();
                }
            });
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it should solve your problem

```js
$(function (){
            $(".checkbox").change(function(e){
              if($("#x2").is(":checked") || $("#xt").is(":checked")){
                 $("#divX2").show();
                }else if((e.currentTarget.id === "x2" && $("#x2").is(":checked")) || (e.currentTarget.id === "xt" && $("#xt").is(":checked"))){
                    $("#divX2").show();
                }else{
                  $("#divX2").hide();
                }
              });
            });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li><span><input name="xt" id="xt" type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/> Check All</span></li>
   <li><span><input name="x1" id="x1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox mark" /> X1</span></li>
   <li><span><input name="x2" id="x2" type="checkbox" class="checkbox mark"/> X2</span></li>
   <li><span><input name="x3" id="x3" type="checkbox" class="checkbox mark"/> X3</span></li>
   <li><span><input name="x4" id="x4" type="checkbox" class="checkbox mark"/> X4</span></li>
</ul>
<div id="divX2" hidden="hidden">
   <h4>Mostrando X2</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `#xt` to the change event

```
$("#x2, #xt").change(function() {
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#xt").click(function() {
    var check = $(this).prop("checked");
    $(".mark").prop("checked", check);
  });

  $("#x2, #xt").change(function() {
    console.log("change x2");
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      $("#divX2").show();
    } else {
      $("#divX2").hide();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><span><input name="xt" id="xt" type="checkbox" /> Check All</span></li>
  <li><span><input name="x1" id="x1" type="checkbox" class="mark" /> X1</span></li>
  <li><span><input name="x2" id="x2" type="checkbox" class="mark"/> X2</span></li>
  <li><span><input name="x3" id="x3" type="checkbox" class="mark"/> X3</span></li>
  <li><span><input name="x4" id="x4" type="checkbox" class="mark"/> X4</span></li>
</ul>
<div id="divX2" hidden="hidden">
  <h4>Mostrando X2</h4>
</div>
```